# Cant access my shared preference in a different activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my first activity I am saving my shared preference as

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
settings.edit().putString("uname", username);
```

Then I am reading it in another activity as

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
  String uname = settings.getString("uname", "");
```

But the uname string is always empty any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is obvious. Look at this

```
settings.edit().putString("uname", username);
```

Here you are trying to save `String` via `SharedPreferences.Editor` but if String could be permanently saved into SharedPreferences you need to call also **commit()** that means that you want to confirm your opperation(s). In other case, your value never be saved.

You can imagine this like one "transaction". If you won't commit transaction, any changes performed in it will be thrown away.

So, correct way is

```
settings.edit().putString("uname", username).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to do .commit

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29

```
settings.edit().putString("uname", username).commit();
```